# How to define a polynomial of two variables in Scilab?

Tags: math, polynomial-math, scilab, polynomials

With `poly` method you can define polynomials.
For example, `3x^3-2x^2-3=0` would be something like:

```
p = poly([-3, 0, -2, 3], 'x', 'coeff')
```

[polynomial definition in Scilab](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/poly.html)

> My problem is that **I need to define this**:
>
> %pi * **x**^2 * **y** - 330 = 0

I have tried this:

```
poly([-330, %pi], 'x^2*y', 'coeff')
```

And this:

```
poly([0,1], 'y', 'coeff') * poly([0,0,%pi], 'x', 'coeff')
```

And other combinations, which obviously didn't work.

[image: In Maxima I did this]

I need to do the same as the image (made in Maxima) for Scilab, but I am stuck on the first step.

I couldn't find more information about this in the Scilab help.

Comment: It does not seem that scilab provides multivariate polynomials. What you want is not possible, you would have to define it as a function in 2 arguments.

Comment: Never used it, but you should be able to use Maxima from Scilab with the toolbox: [SciMax](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/scimax/)